# Can I ask "what are the topmost difficult verses for translators?"

Tags: discussion

It appears to be open ended, but this question is  open ended too [Which 'modern' English translation of the Bible is considered the 'closest' or most accurate translation?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4/which-modern-english-translation-of-the-bible-is-considered-the-closest-or-m)

Is my question valid under the rules? any suggestion to make it more specific?

"What are the most difficult or controversial translation verses or issues faced by mainstream translators or bible versions" ? Do the textual critics and translators discuss some verses which are most difficult with strong significance?

Comment: It could only be "opinion based" in a way that the "literal translation" question isn't.

Comment: what do you mean @David I should be specific to literal word for word translations that makes it acceptable?

Comment: No, I mean that your interest involves opinion to a much greater degree than the translation question. We'll see what others think, though!

Comment: Please note that the question referenced here was locked (before you asked this question) precisely to prevent it from being used as a precedent in this way: "This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here..." (But thank you for asking on Meta prior to posing the question on the main site.)

Comment: @Susan can you give some link or article here that contains a list of most significant translation issues? BTW Gal3:21 remains most significant issue (for me) and i cant find any discussion over it even you did not mention of any records from scholars translators etc. Plz try to raise that ques in your circle. Perhaps its most kept secret translation issue which they are hiding.

Answer (score 1):

No, that would be both opinion based and a list question.